# Having problems with axios.post while try to get data FROM server

Tags: reactjs, rest, post, axios

I am trying to use axios.post (in TS) to get responses from server (using POST as GET) without sending any Data. The server sends back the Data but REACT cant handle the responses.

Here is the react component:

```
interface allComapnies {
    comapniesData:CompanyData[];
 }

function GetAllCompanies(props:allComapnies): JSX.Element {
    const myURL = globals.urls.admin+"get_company/all";

    const [comapniesData,setData] = useState([new CompanyData()]);

    useEffect(()=>{axios.post(myURL).then((response)=>{
            console.log(response.data);
            setData(response.data);
        }).catch(error=>{console.log(error)});
    },[]);


    return (
        <div className="getAllCompanies">
             {comapniesData.map(item=><OneCompany
                key ={item.id}
                id={item.id}
                name={item.name}
                email={item.email}
            />)}
        </div>
    );
}

export default GetAllCompanies;
```

The console message shows:

Error: Request failed with status code 302

- at createError (createError.js:16)
- at settle (settle.js:17)
- at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:54)

The browser get the responses from the server:

> [{id: 2, name: "company2", email: "hgfytj@fdgreg", password: "trjyjytk",…},…]

The function of the REST Post inside the Controller in the Server(SPRING):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("admin")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "localhost:3000", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AdminController extends ClientController {
    private final AdminService adminService;

...
 
@PostMapping("get_company/all")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllCompanies() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(adminService.getAllCompanies(), HttpStatus.FOUND);
  }

...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was that I sent http status number 302 as a send confirmation, instead of number 200.

This prevented the server from sending the desired information in response. I have now changed the status to 200 and the information is received even when sending "axios.post" with an empty request.

```
@PostMapping("get_company/all")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllCompanies() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(adminService.getAllCompanies(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try GET method instead POST cause you are getting data from your DB and not sending it to.

Comment: I'm purposely using POST because GET send the information by URL and less secured.  Besides, a blank POST can be used to request information from the server. Indeed it works when I use API platforms

Comment: POST also shouldn't be trusted outright. Indeed, malicious intent can easily fake POST request.
If it's an information user must not see, don't send it to him :) .
Maybe this will help: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30754/is-there-a-difference-between-get-and-post-for-web-application-security?rq=1